# Get info about a stack with the tiff class in Matlab

Tags: matlab, tiff

I'm trying to open a stack containing tiff images with Matlab [Tiff class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiff-class.html) and get informations (Height,Width, Number of images) about the stack/the images in it.

My **question** is the following: I would like to know how to access information from the "class" object, i.e. t in the example below.

Let's say my stack is named 'OriginalStack.tif', then when I type

```
t = Tiff('OriginalStack.tif','r')
```

I get the following output:

```
t = 

                  TIFF File: '/Users/catherine/Documents/MATLAB/OriginalStack.tif'
                       Mode: 'r'
    Current Image Directory: 1
           Number Of Strips: 1
                SubFileType: Tiff.SubFileType.Default
                Photometric: Tiff.Photometric.RGB
                ImageLength: 364
                 ImageWidth: 460
               RowsPerStrip: 364
              BitsPerSample: 8
                Compression: Tiff.Compression.None
               SampleFormat: Tiff.SampleFormat.UInt
            SamplesPerPixel: 3
        PlanarConfiguration: Tiff.PlanarConfiguration.Chunky
           ImageDescription: ImageJ=1.48v
images=20
slices=20
loop=false

                Orientation: Tiff.Orientation.TopLeft
```

The height,  width and number of images are all correct (obviously), however I don't know hot to get them from t and I have to  use `imfinfo('OriginalStack.tif')` to get this information. Sorry if I'm not using the right terminology here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By consulting the [TIFF Reader](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiff-class.html) documentation, you would use a method called [`getTag`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiff.gettag.html) for the TIFF object.  What you specify as an input is a string for the field of the `Tiff` instance you want.  For example, if you wanted the samples per pixel, you would do:

```
samplesPerPixel = t.getTag('SamplesPerPixel');
```

Make sure you type in how the field is spelled **exactly**.  This is case sensitive.  For more information, check out this link: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/importing-images.html#br_c8to-1 .  It has some great examples on reading in TIFF stacks and extracting their metadata, but because you already have all of the fields displayed from `imfinfo`, just pick out the field you want, then use that as a parameter into `getTag` string formatted.

Comment: Great! I looked at this documentation but did not make the link with the tag and the property. I was also confused by the lines "images","slices" and"loop" but just figured out that it was the continuity of the tag "ImageDescription". Thanks!

Comment: @Benoit_11 - I was actually confused about the "images","slices" and "loop" stuff too!  Looks like you figured that out and I learned something :) Glad I helped.